# Php undefine variable issue

Tags: php

Following is the function which provide random string... but i'm getting this error message
**Notice: Undefined variable: str in C:\xampp\htdocs\webrootfinal\forgotpasspr.php on line 5.........**

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  
$size = strlen( $chars );
for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
$str.= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}
return $str;                        
}
$my_string = rand_string( 10 );
```

Any Idea or Solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `$str` a value before you start concatenating to it.

Comment: Thanks, @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.